# jQuery :contains selector isn't working as expected

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select calendar event titles that have a specific word and use this to change the background colour of the event.

Please see my code below. This changes all events to have the background colour of red even if event title doesn't contain the word 'Test'. I've even changed 'Test' to 'uhrguqhergoieqhrgeurgherogih' but it still changes everything.

Unfortunately I can't see anything similar on SO so hopefully one of you could help me out please! :)

Thanks in advance!

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    if($(".fc-event-title:contains('Test')"))
    {
      $('.fc-event').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `$(".fc-event-title:contains('Test')").css('background-color', 'red')`

Comment: no need for the if condition

Comment: @satpal thanks for your comment. Unfortunately this only changes the background colour of the text instead of the whole event block :)

Comment: @guradio thanks for your comment. I've removed the if condition but the result is still the same, I'm afraid.

Comment: Try `$(".fc-event-title:contains('Test')").closest('.fc-event').css('background-color'‌​, 'red')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `if` condition.Do it directly like below:-

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $(".fc-event-title:contains('Test')").css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

If above not worked then try with `closest()` like below:-

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $(".fc-event-title:contains('Test')").closest('.fc-event').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. Unfortunately this only changes the background colour of the text instead of the whole event block :)

Comment: @S.Pearson  glad to help you :):)